# Google Compule Engine: Running multiple containers

Tags: google-compute-engine, containers, gcloud

Is there a way to automate creation of a VM instance with more than one container running? I can create a VM with one container running when using `gcloud`. Basically, is there an easy way to achieve this without manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are using GCP  Container-Optimized OS (COS) images. Per their [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations) section You can only deploy one container for each VM instance. Consider [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) if you need to deploy multiple containers per VM instance.